# npm update is not honoring the results of npm outdated

Tags: npm, npm-update, npm-outdated

I ran `npm outdated` on a project - it showed that there were several outdated packages. So I ran `npm update` - it updated a few packages but not all. If I run `npm outdated` again it still shows the remaining packages that are outdated:

`Package                       Current        Wanted  Latest
babel-loader                    7.1.1         7.1.1   7.1.2
babel-runtime                  6.23.0        6.23.0  6.26.0
chalk                           2.0.1         2.0.1   2.1.0
css-loader                     0.28.4        0.28.4  0.28.5
eslint                          4.2.0         4.2.0   4.5.0
eslint-plugin-react             7.1.0         7.1.0   7.2.1
fs-extra                        4.0.0         4.0.0   4.0.1
html-webpack-plugin            2.29.0        2.29.0  2.30.1
material-ui              1.0.0-beta.5  1.0.0-beta.5  0.19.0
postcss-flexbugs-fixes          3.0.0         3.0.0   3.2.0
react-stripe-elements           0.0.2         0.0.2   0.0.7
webpack                         3.3.0         3.3.0   3.5.5
webpack-dev-server              2.5.1         2.5.1   2.7.1
webpack-manifest-plugin         1.1.2         1.1.2   1.3.1`

If I try to run `npm update` again, it does nothing!

Why are the two commands telling me different things?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run `npm update` and some of the packages defined in `package.json` have their version pinned, it will not update. That is why you see three columns when you run `npm outdated`. The current installed version, the latest version that matches what is defined in your `package.json`, and finally, the actual latest version.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, @aherriot. Very clear now!